# Firebase : How to structure group post with likes?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This are what I have tried so far.

**Group Posts**

```
{
    "group_posts":{
        "group_push_key":{
            "foo":"bar",
            "biz":"baz",
        }
    }
}
```

**Likes**

```
{
    "group_likes":{
        "group_push_key":{
            "user_uid1":true,
            "user_uid2":true,
            "user_uid3":true
        }
    }
}
```

By using this setup, I could detect if the user already liked a post by querying from ref `group_likes/{group_push_key}/{user_uid1}` equal to `true`.

My problem with this setup is the tracking of like count. I sure can do `snap.numChildren()` but this only returns the count of the snapshot returned. Is there an existing/standard way of doing this `post`x`likes` relationship in firebase?

**PS**

I was thinking of having a node server which will watch every `child_added` or `child_removed` event then change the like count accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should denormalise your like counts with a simple summarisation field in your structure and increment/decrement it everytime there's a like action.

```
{
"group_posts":{
    "group_push_key":{
        "foo":"bar",
        "biz":"baz",
        "likes_count":0,
    }
}
```

Firebase indexing relies heavily on denormalisation strategies.

The approach you mentioned is something like a reactor (https://divshot.com/blog/development/fire-stack/), it really depends if you want to have a serverless architecture or not, but it is a valid strategy indeed. You lose the serverless concept and have to maintain an infrastructure (as simple as it is, you still need it) but in the other hand it's easier to keep the denormalised data nodes in sync.

*** Update ***
You can actually keep it serverless using Google Cloud Functions (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).